# How to run my UI automation test class on android studio?

Tags: android, adb, android-uiautomator

I was trying to make a `UI` Automator that can press Home and find my setting and click on it. I don't know how to run this on Android Studio, because there is no default Activity, will it work on using the ADB?

Here is a part of my code, is there something wrong with it?

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@SdkSuppress(minSdkVersion = 18)
public class MainActivity  {

    @Test
    public void testA() throws Exception{
        UiDevice mDevice =UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
        mDevice.pressHome();
        UiScrollable searchsetting = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true));
        searchsetting.scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text("Settings"));
        mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().text("Settings")).clickAndWaitForNewWindow();

    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't have to have any activity.You just have to create an Android project. And then create your Ui Test. Your test class should look like:
[image]

Click on the play icon your test will run. If you need an example on how you should launch Settings. Please have a look [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/UiAutomator/src/com/android/test/uiautomator/demos/LaunchSettings.java)

Comment: thanks,but when I try to run ,it said that I need a defult activity,that's why i am so confused about it,how should i solve this situation

Comment: Could you please try to create new project with no activity option from the wizard and then put your code in the `ExampleInstrumentedTest` and run it again? Please don't forget to add dependency for  UiAutomator in gradle

Comment: Great! Happy to hear that.